# Combine all sass files into a single file

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

Is there any option available in gulp-sass to combine sass files?

For example:

**main.scss:**

```
$var: red;
```

**control.scss:**

```
@import 'main';
.a{
  color: $var;
}
```

The combined output file should be single scss file like below

```
$var: red;
.a{
  color: $var;
}
```

Comment: This would be really useful for component libraries, rather than providing only a compiled .css file.

Answer (score 17):

Did you try something like this?

```
gulp = require('gulp');
concat = require('gulp-concat');

// the default task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('./*.scss')
       .pipe(concat('all.scss'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

This should produce a single combined scss in `./dist/all.scss`.

I don't know if `@import` statements are handled correctly, but these 
issues are usually handled by *ad-hoc* modules (for example, [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)), which produce a `.css` output...

Comment: thanks for the update. Your code compiled as css file, but the output should be a scss file I expected.

Comment: Sorry: why do you want `scss` in output? You usually want to output css to public...

Comment: Yeah I can get the css file in the destination, but I need to provide the scss file too, so that they can manually edit and compile them-self.

Comment: Yes, sorry... To do what you ask, it should suffice `gulp.src + concat + gulp.dest`... See my updated answer...

Comment: As you posed this solution does not honor `@import` statements.

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution, full proof solution. You need to use gulp-scss-combine as well.

```
(function(r){
    const gulp = r('gulp'); 
    const combine = r('gulp-scss-combine');
    const concat = r('gulp-concat');

    gulp.task('combine-scss', ()=>gulp.src('scss/**')  // define a source files
        .pipe(combine())   // combine them based on @import and save it to stream
        .pipe(concat('style.scss')) // concat the stream output in single file
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))  // save file to destination.
    );
})(require);
```

You can play with code here . [code](https://repl.it/@henryjackson1/BlaringPitifulCarat) , basically doing same thing but not in gulp but a node.js standard application. just delete all.scss file or its content, then run the program. you will see the result.

Comment: The Repl.it link is super helpful to figure out what is going on with `gulp-scss-combine` since the repo doesn't have too many docs: https://github.com/DeathMark/gulp-scss-combine

Answer (score -4):

You have to execute one file that imports all other scss files, but when you listen the changes, you have to listen the changes of all files in the scss directory.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
      // You have to execute one file that import all other scss files
      return gulp.src('src/scss/*.scss')
              .pipe(sass())
              .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
    });



gulp.task('watch', function() {
      // You have to listen the all files in the scss directory
      gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss',['sass']);     
  });
```