# Combine all scss file to one css file using gulp

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp

I have this gulpfile.js file.

Here, you can see that every **.scss** file is converted to the corresponding **.css** file but I want all **.scss** files will be converted to only one **.css** file which will be main.css. How can I do this?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function(done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
    });
    done();
})

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync', 'sass', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch("app/*.html", { events: 'all' }, function(cb) {
        browserSync.reload();
        cb();
    });
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
}));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine all sass files into a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133297/combine-all-sass-files-into-a-single-file)

Comment: You can also use `_xyz.scss` to not compile it into an independent file but to use it as partial.

Comment: @Mr_Green so you mean I can rename all .scss file to `_anything.scss` and it will automatically converted to 1 .css file?

Comment: @Mr_Green so you mean I can rename all .scss file to `_anything.scss` and it will automatically converted to 1 .css file?

Comment: Not just that.. you need also to use `@import` in main scss file to include those partials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried putting in a concat before the piping in a destination?  You'll need to import the concat function found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat).  The following should combine your files.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        // concat will combine all files declared in your "src"
        .pipe(concat('all.scss'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
    });
```

Comment: let me try it now

Comment: It's working but other .scss file code it added to the top of the main.scss file. can I place to the bottom? also, shall I need to use combine?

Comment: you mean you have import statements at the top of main.scss?

Comment: well, I don't have an import statement now but I will set the scss folder like multiple `_.anything.scss` file and one `main.scss` file. In this `main.scss` flle I will use `import` all  `_anything.scss` file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you have _anything.scss imported into your main.scss, then it should get compiled and combined along with everything else in your main.scss.  I don't believe you would need to use a combine or anything like that and I also wouldn't think that the you should worry about the order of the imports in terms of how it builds.  I guess I'm just not sure what problem you are running into now that you're able to concat.

Comment: @Shibbir better to use `@import` or `@use` and keep the partials in sequence as needed.

Comment: @dogyear anyways, It' working great fine. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @dogyear one more help. as you can see when I save changed the `index.html` file it automatically reloads the browser but if I change any other .html file then it's not reloading the browser. Do you know why?

Comment: Hmm... If they're not triggering the reload then they're not being watched.  Your wildcard isn't including subfolders.  instead of "app/*.html" try ""app/**/*.html".  Same as your did for your scss watch

Comment: @dogyear all the html file exists in the app folder.

Comment: Hmm... I dunno.  Have you tried just using "gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload)" instead of the other things you have going on? I'm not sure what "events:all" and "cb()" does.  Not sure if they're interfering with everything else.  If that doesn't work you might want to pose this as another question and see if someone else has the answer.