# Combine multiple Dart SCSS files into one

Tags: sass

I am developing a small scss library with some mixins and other stuff to use to some of my projects.

This library has a couple of dozens of files and folders/subfolders.

As it is right now, it's very hard to use and update, and I am looking for a way to bundle all the scss files into one, with all the code uncompilled.

I am using @use instead of @import since the latter is about to become obsolete according to documentation (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).

I haven't found much online to help me.
In this post [Combining Multiple SASS files into one SASS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109211/combining-multiple-sass-files-into-one-sass-file) scss-bundler is mentioned, but the project seems to be a bit abandoned and couldn't find what I want in the documentation.

This is the github repo of the project:
https://github.com/TheoKondak/Sinister/tree/main/src