# What does this mean >> ~/.zshrc?

Tags: zsh, rbenv

Can someone clarify me the difference between these two lines?

```
export PATH=./bin:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
```

and

```
export PATH=./bin:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH >> ~/.zshrc
```

What is this doing?

```
>> ~/.zshrc
```

This is written in a .zshrc file. Which language is used there? Where I can learn the syntax? The export, eval etc.

Comment: Cross-site related question https://serverfault.com/q/196734/496616

Comment: More about IO redirection http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/4969641/8186898

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually this is used outside of the `.zshrc` file (or `.bashrc` file or similar) to add something to it, for example you would normally write something like the following:

```
echo 'export PATH=./bin:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc
```

This will write the export setting within the quotes to your `.zshrc` file so that, assuming you are using ZSH as your shell, it will get executed when you log in.

The fact that the line actually in your `.zshrc` file contains this would appear to be an error. In this case it will write the output from the export command to the `.zshrc` file every time you log in. The export command outputs nothing, so this extra part will essentially do nothing, and should probably be removed so you are left with just the first line.

Answer (score 14):

it means:

- `>>` is **append to**
- `~` is **file located in current user's home directory**
- `.zshrc` is **file called .zshrc**